# How to get specific part of webpage in mvc?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to get a specific part of current page to save it in another file for example in a PDF file.

I want to get this part of current view in **ActionResult** when I click on submit:

```
<div id="t1" name="t1">
  .......
</div>
```

I tried to use this code to get :

```
client = new WebClient();
string url = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

string content = "";
Stream data = client.OpenRead(url);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data);
content = sr.ReadToEnd();
data.Flush();
data.Close();
```

But I want to get only tag div named **t1** from current page.

**NOTE**: I don't want to use jquery. I only want to do it in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for this sort of thing...

example code block;

```
   public string GetContent(string url)
    {

        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(url);
        HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='t1']");

        return node.InnerHtml;
    }
```

Comment: But an error occurred:
_An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in YourProject.dll but was not handled in user code_

Comment: `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='t1']");`
returns null

Comment: Yes. I added but It still returns null.

Comment: i tried it , its working well  ,i guess you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I think something works wrong because on another page it works.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: My problem is when call `hw.Load(url)` **hw** doesn't load current url and it goes to open login page because no page can open without login.

Comment: Because of this problem, **doc** can not find `"//div[@id='t1']"` because there is no `<div id="t1" name="t1">` in login page.

Comment: well you have pass login page first  to access your current page then.

Comment: I can not pass username and password to login page because username and password are called from the form of the login page as: `string Username = Request.Form["username"];`

Comment: if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal) return userlogged .. whatever. on login aspx.  coz your request will be local

Comment: but `hw.Load(url)` doesn't work with **HttpContext.Current**. It may run a new browser.

Comment: here is my code in mvc:
       `[AllowAnonymous]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult LogIn(string rtn = "/")
        {
            string Username = Request.Form["username"];
            string password = Request.Form["password"];`